# Thumbnail datagrid implementation c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, windows-explorer

Is there a way to implement a thumbnail preview for a data grid in a WPF like there is in windows explorer. Like so..
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BedsK.png)

Because my data grid has a few thousand rows of image files and if i wanted to delete a particular file after a file type search and to make sure i am deleting the right file i have to open it and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Few questions that will solve your issue.

does the datagrid contains file names that already saved to your local ? 
if yes you can have datagrid on selection changed, get the bitmap image out of string path(the selected image path) and assign this bitmap to the source of the image control.

and by this once you changed the selection the image control will show the selected image.

Comment: Yea my datagrid shows the filepath, filename and the filesize.